# Skyrim - Will I lose my fox if I move?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I purchased Lake Manor on Falkreath Land in Skyrim. I have a daughter and the boy named Hroar as my children. I want to move to Solitude, but my daughter has found a pet fox and I do not want to lose it.

If I move, will she lose her pet fox or will it come with us?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I want a pet fox

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Animals will move where ever you move. So I think it's okay.

Comment: Thank you! I moved and you are right - she kept the fox! Thanks!